# password less sudo access for deploy user

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, sudo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ubuntu - how can I avoid typing a password on every admin action?](https://serverfault.com/questions/99952/ubuntu-how-can-i-avoid-typing-a-password-on-every-admin-action)

Googled and tried various approaches to solve the password-less sudo access commands, but none seem worked for me. The server is Ubuntu 10.04

I've a deploy user under deploy group.
I added the deploy user 
Through google search and even all SF search combination, nothing worked. Following is my `/etc/sudoers` file

```
deploy@myserver:~$ id
uid=1000(deploy) gid=1001(deploy) groups=0(root),107(admin),1001(deploy),1002(rvm)
deploy@myserver:~$ groups
deploy root admin rvm
deploy@myserver:~$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers
# /etc/sudoers
Defaults    env_reset
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
deploy  ALL=(ALL) ALL
#deploy ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL

%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL
deploy@myserver:~$
```

When I try to open up `/etc/sudoers` with `visudo` command, Permission denied

```
deploy@myserver:~$ visudo
visudo: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
visudo: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
deploy@myserver:~$
```

Comment: can you try "sudo visudo"?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Oh! holy cow! What was I smoking??? Sorry guys.

Answer (score 2):

How would you expect `sudo` to do its magic if you don't actually use `sudo`? What you need to do here is run `sudo visudo`.

Comment: Yup, holy cow! What was I smoking??? Sorry buddy.